# How to downgrade back to an older version of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I upgraded to OSX Catalina, and in the process of fixing broken packages managed to inadvertently upgrade `posgresql` from version 11 to version 12. When I try to start `postgresql` I see the following in the log:

```
2020-07-18 17:51:16.885 AEST [42394] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2020-07-18 17:51:16.885 AEST [42394] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 12.3.
```

How do I remove version 12, and then reinstall version 11? I am not sure which which minor release of version 11 I am using. I prefer to use `brew`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

to upgrade the databases from a previous version retaining all data.

Information per: brew info postgres

If you really want to downgrade then

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql@11
```

would do that.